# Using Apply on a function with multidimensional input

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, slot

I have a user defined function which takes multidimensional input, e.g a function that takes two algebraic variables a and b as well as a matrix m and computes some rule function as:

```
f[a_,b_,m_] := {a :> m[[1,1]]*a + m[[2,1]]*b, b :> m[[1,2]]*a + m[[2,2]]*b}
```

Now if I had a similar function over **just** single variables, e.g `g[a,b,c,d]` I could perform said function using the syntax `g @@ vec` where `vec = {a,b,c,d}`. What I would like achieve is something like:

```
v = {a,b}
m = {{p,q},{r,s}}
f @@ {v,m}
```

but doing so produces

> ```
> f[{a, b}, {{p, q}, {r, s}}]
> ```

since the braces encompassing the {a,b} variable have been retained. This problem also occurs for the use of `Slot`, producing identical output for `f[#1,#2] &[v,m]` and even just `f[#, m] &[v]`. Neither `Join[v,m]` or `Catenate[{v,m}]` produce a useful list to apply.

How can pass a function a list and then a matrix and have it evaluated in the correct manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this and here are just some examples to get you going into the right direction.

First note that you might simply use `Sequence`:

```
f[a_,b_,m_] := {a :> m[[1,1]]*a + m[[2,1]]*b, b :> m[[1,2]]*a + m[[2,2]]*b}

v = {a , b};
m = {{p,q},{r,s}};

f @@ { Sequence @@ v, m }
```

produces

```
(*
{a :> {{p, q}, {r, s}}[[1, 1]] a + {{p, q}, {r, s}}[[2, 1]] b,
 b :> {{p, q}, {r, s}}[[1, 2]] a + {{p, q}, {r, s}}[[2, 2]] b}
*)
```

You might also add the vector as a special case to your function definition:

```
f[ {a_, b_}, m_] := {a :> m[[1,1]]*a + m[[2,1]]*b, b :> m[[1,2]]*a + m[[2,2]]*b}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of naively trying `Join[v,m]` or `Catenate[{v,m}]`, instead you must add an extra level to the matrix argument, using either:

```
Join[v,{m}]
(* or *)
Catenate[{v,{m}}]
```

which both produce the result

> ```
> {a, b, {{p, q}, {r, s}}}
> ```

such that you can now use `f @@ Join[v,{m}]` to produce the desired output

> ```
> {a :> a {{p, q}, {r, s}}[[1, 1]] + b {{p, q}, {r, s}}[[2, 1]], 
>  b :> a {{p, q}, {r, s}}[[1, 2]] + b {{p, q}, {r, s}}[[2, 2]]}
> ```

Comment: `f @@ Append[v, m]` will also work.